# Azure Devops git repository permissions: how to prioritize 'Allow' over 'Deny'?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I have a git repository created in Azure Devops. I need to restrict access to it in such a way that the repo is accessible only for TeamA. When I set Deny for all other groups and Allow only for TeamA, the permission Deny takes preference when the user belongs to both Contributors and TeamA. Would you please help me to achieve this? I cannot grant access to all contributors except for those in TeamA.

I tried security settings in repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Not Set` permission as an implicit Deny. As you've discovered, explicit `Deny` takes precedence over explicit `Allow`.